# Function returning too many list items and duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, random

This is for a poker app (practice/first app I'm creating). The first function creates a single card, the second should create a Hole (the first 2 cards in Texas Hold'em). I'm trying to get the second function to call the first function, check for duplicates, then return 2 cards (made up of 2 items from RANK and 2 from SUIT). It's returning more than 2 cards though and I don't know why.

It's returning two lists in the output. 2 of which are duplicates, but I don't know if it's how I appended them in the first function that's at fault or something else.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from random import choice
from random import randint

class Cards(object):
    RANK = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A']
    SUIT = ['Club','Diamond','Heart','Spade']
 #Creates One random card/suit combo   
    def picker(self):
        pick=[]
        pick.append(choice(self.RANK))
        pick.append(choice(self.SUIT))
        return pick

#'Should' create 2 cards, check that they aren't dupes, and return them.
    def hole(self):
        hold=[]
        nodup=[]
        while len(hold)<5:
            nodup.append(self.picker())
            if nodup not in hold:
                hold.append(nodup)
            else:
                hold.append(self.picker())
                continue
        return hold
```

When I call the function, I get this-

```
>>> from cards import Cards
>>> test=Cards().hole()
>>> test
    [[[2, 'Heart'], ['Q', 'Spade'], [2, 'Diamond'], [9, 'Club'], [1, 'Diamond']], [5, 'Heart'], [5, 'Heart'], [5, 'Club'], ['K', 'Heart']]

I want-
>>> [2, 'Heart'], ['Q', 'Spade']
```

Comment: Even though there are two perfectly good alternative implementations proposed below. You should look over your code and ask yourself how it in any way matches what your required output is. For instance you want two cards, yet you loop 5 times. You are performing operations on two lists (including appending one list to another) and circumventing your own duplicate check after you do find a duplicate.

Comment: @PaulRooney, I looped 4 times (it's <5, so it should stop on the 4th time, right?) because in the interpreter, "len(picker())" would give me 2. So 2 items in one list make up one card. I had this explanation in my original post, but removed a bunch of stuff for clarity. Is that not what's happening? And about 'circumventing my own dup check', I'm not sure what you're referring to. Is it this "hold.append(self.picker())"? I was thinking that would simply pick another random combo, similar to ellio's "hold[1] = self.picker()" I'm going to close this thread, but message me if you want to answer.

Comment: @PaulRooney Seems comments don't just shut down once you chose a best answer. So yeah, if you can answer that, I would appreciate it. That was my original question, I wasn't looking for easier ways to do what I was trying, but why the way I was trying it wasn't working. A solution that doesn't come from me doesn't help me get better. But it's hard to come up with a solution if I don't see the problem either...

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what `list.append` does. The functionality you are expecting is that of `list.extend`. `append` is literally adding an item to the list. If its another list it becomes a sub list. `extend` on the other hand adds the lists together to make a single larger list. The docs will explain it more clearly. `hold.append(self.picker())` adds to the outputted list `hold` without checking if its a duplicate. I think @elliospizzaman's answer demonstrates how you could refactor your code to be correct.  @Randy C's answer shows a superior method to model a deck of cards.

Comment: @PaulRooney I will definitely check '.extend' out. I read the docs when I can. I also used 'nodup.append(self.picker())' 'if nodup not in hold:' 'hold.append(nodup)' wrong too, I think. Looking at it closer, 'nodupe' will just keep being added to for 4 loops. It's not that I was thinking .append would act like .extend, it's that I wasn't thinking at all and was just assuming 'nodupe' should've been constantly replaced by new values. Of course that wasn't and it was just getting longer and longer because of the 4 loops. I think I get it now. Thanks! (I also need to figure out mini markdown)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way to get what you want:

```
def hole(self):
    hold=[]
    # Pick two cards
    hold.append(self.picker())
    hold.append(self.picker())
    # Make sure the cards aren't the same
    while hold[0]==hold[1]:
        hold[1] = self.picker()
    return hold
```

Although, as Randy C has pointed out, there are much better ways to do this.

Comment: Both of your solutions are great. I'm trying to do as much 'by hand' though so I'll go with yours and meld it into what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off just creating something closer to a deck of cards. For example, you can use `itertools.product` to create all the individual cards, `random.shuffle` to mix them up, and `list.pop` to deal one at a time:

```
In [46]: from itertools import product

In [47]: from random import shuffle

In [48]: RANK = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A']

In [49]: SUIT = ['Club','Diamond','Heart','Spade']

In [50]: cards = list(product(RANK, SUIT))

In [51]: shuffle(cards)

In [52]: cards.pop()
Out[52]: (3, 'Spade')

In [53]: cards.pop()
Out[53]: (10, 'Club')

In [54]: len(cards)
Out[54]: 54
```

Also, looking at the length at the end -- you've got both 1 and A in your ranks.